# I send you all to the Connect-Wall

Tags: pattern, knowledge, letters, movies, connect-wall

[image]
Here's a random code-wall for you though; I think of it as unfair to the point of impossible, but some people of this site never cease to surprise me. You need to split the 16 words into 4 groups, such that each of them has something in common.

> eon kin yen win lame brat tell gull river reckon least stork santa edward dante joy

**Hint 1**

Due to the question about the exclusiveness, I consulted an expert on the question. Though I recorded the conversation, the microphone was too far from me so most of my speech is illegible (not that you really needed it, huh?)

> ME: So, ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ exclusive? 
>  EXPERT: No, if I understood the criteria, both "eon" and "joy" can be classified into a group different from their assigned ones.
>  ME: Excuse me, but how? ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■, ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■, ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ "h" ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■? 
>  EXPERT: Not really; you would have known it if you read the books. 
>  ME: ■■■■■■, ■■■■. ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■, ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ mother ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■? 
>  EXPERT: ...All right, I didn't think of it that way. Then yes, it's an "Only-connect wall". *mumbling* (the idea still sucks though)

**Hint 2 /triggered by Kristina/ (btw group 1 is technically wrong)**

> *Every* group has something to do with "Game of Thrones". Sorry. Also, as I stated before, they're exclusive.

Comment: Does membership in each group have to be exclusive? I.e. If a group is "3-letter words" can there be a 3-letter word in any other group?

Comment: @WAF this sound a lot like Only Connect's wall puzzle, so probably not.

Comment: @WAF Not exclusive. I'll make this clearer in the first hint.

Comment: I'm interested in the fact that there's a [tag:movies] tag on the puzzle. None of those words instantly pop out at being movie-related, or connected to any movies I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: Are the groups all the same size?

Comment: @WAF Well, seems like I was wrong. Exclusive it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Group 1

> All Starks off by one letter:
> Santa (Sansa) - Edward (Eddard) - Reckon (Rickon) - Brat (Bran)

Group 2

> Ending letters of a GoT house:
> Yen (Targaryen) - Joy (Greyjoy) - Tell (Martell) - Eon (Baratheon)

Group 3

> One letter off from a word in a GoT book title:
> Dante (Dance) - Least (Feast) - Stork (Storm) - Lame (Game)

Group 4

> Beginnings of GoT cities and castles?
> River (Riverrun) - Win (Winterfell) - Kin (King's Landing) - Gull (Gulltown)

As to hint 1:

> Eon and joy could be in group 1 (Jon).

Answer (score 2):

Well, I have an attempt!

Group 1:

> reckon // santa // brat // edward: all Game of Thrones character first names off by one letter (rIckon, sanSa, braN, edDard)

Group 2:

> eon // yen // win // kin: all 3 letters/all ending in N

Group 3:

> stork // least // dante // river: all 5 letters long

Group 4:

> lame // joy // gull // tell: each can have their first letters be replaced with "C" and still form valid words

Comment: A really good one, probably better than my intended answer. However, we can get 'eon' to c group, and 'santa' to 5-letter group, and see the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Category 1:

> Game of Thrones houses/surnames with only last syllable:
>  Mar**TELL**, Grey**JOY**, Targar**YEN**, Barath**EON**

Category 2:

> Stark names, one letter out:
>  reckon, santa, edward, stork >> Rickon, Sansa, Eddard, Stark.

Category 3:

> Unsure, potential words:
>  river lame brat least kin gull

Category 4:

> Words to do with Tywin Lannister, combining above methods of difference.
>  dante >> played by Charles **DANCE**
>  win >> Ty**WIN** Lannister
>  Unsure of last 2, potential words:
>  river lame brat least kin gull

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured out three of the groups:

> Win Reckon Gull Tell - each can have "ing" added to the end to make a new word 
>  Kin Lame Eon River - each can have a letter added to the beginning to make a new word: Skin Flame Aeon Driver 
> Santa Edward Dante Least - each is an anagram of a word: Antas Warded Anted Steal

Is this right so far?

Comment: I'm sorry, man, I'm new at this kind of puzzles. See the hint for yourself. (Atnas is very obscure for an anagram, though)